# How to get the clicked choice in the closing form dialog?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, formclosing

When I close the *Form* appear this DialogBox

[image: Close dialog Box]

I need to get the action clicked in this dialog (for example Yes or No etc...) in Form's method *canClose*
In debug the last point is in:

*\Forms\MyForm\Methods\canClose*

```
ret = super();
```

How I can get the clicked choice?

Thanks in advice.

Comment: Consider accepting an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get the answer from the prompt.
The return value of `super` is true, if the user can leave the form.

You do not describe what you want to achieve, but "No" is the answer to your question.

The prompt comes when a value in the record is change and the users press the Esc key. If the user selects Yes, the `write` method is called. So you may set a flag `canClose` and then test it in `write`. But I honestly not see the reason why this would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Check some lookup and dialog forms.
They uses `closeOk`, `closedOk`, `closeCancel` and `closedCancel` methods.
There are also `closeSelect` and `closeSelectRecord` methods to assign selected record (check also `selectMode` method on the form).

Comment: Hi @Matej, thanks for the reply, but with this way I did't find the solution. I appreace your hel, but I'm not able to get the action selected.